# How to remove a navigationController (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller

My app has couple of normal views (V1, V2), without a navigationController, but when and ADD button is pushed creates a view with a navigationController like this:

CreateNewEventViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];


    tableViewController = [[NewEventTableViewController alloc] init];

    navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:tableViewController];
    tableViewController.navigationController.title = @"Add";

    [self.view addSubview:navigationController.view];
}
```

so the NewEventTableViewController is an UITableViewController. When done filling the data from the table, last cell is a button to save it and then go back to one of the main views (V1, V2).

NewEventTableViewController.m

```
V1 *myV1 = [[V1 alloc] init];
[self.view.superview addSubview:myV1.view];
```

but the navigationController I had stays. Any way of removing it?

**update**
I've tried this, but all I get is a white screen. Also removing after adding the new view. (this code is placed in NewEventTableViewController)

```
[self.navigationController.view removeFromSuperview];
    V1 *myV1 = [[V1 alloc] init];
    [self.view addSubview:myV1.view];
```

**update 2**
Is not what I really needed but anyway I can use this.

```
[self.navigationController.view.superview removeFromSuperview];
```

it removes the navigationController and it's table view and it displays the view I had before I call the CreateNewEventViewController.

Comment: Sorry, I dont really know how to do it without actually trying it myself :(

Comment: can you explain what you want to do

Comment: Instead of adding the navigationController as a subview, why not use presentModalViewController and dismissModalViewControllerAnimated?

Answer (score 0):

Not much sure why you wanna do that, but there is a possibility to hide navigationController

self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;

Comment: I wan't to do it because I only want the navigationController for the view addObject but not for the main views of the app.